# OpenCL: Writing to pointer in main memory

Tags: opencl

Is it possible, using OpenCL's DMA capabilities, to write to a main memory address that is passed into the cl program? I understand doing so would likely break the program, but the intent here is to run a GPU process and then overwrite the address space of the CPU program used to run it, so breakage is expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Which version of the OpenCL API are you targeting? 
In OpenCL 2.0 and above you can use Shared Virtual Memory (SVM)  to share address between host and device(s) in platforms that support it. 
You can get more information about it in the [Intel OpenCL SVM overview](http://%20https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-20-shared-virtual-memory-overview).

If you are using previous versions, or your hardware does not support it, you can use pinned memory with the appropriate flags to clCreateBuffer. In particular, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, see [clCreateBuffer in Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html).

Note that, when using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR has some alignment restrictions.
In general, in OpenCL, when and how the DMA is used depends on the hardware platform, so you should refer to the vendor documentation for details.